# Naming convention in Objective C /C , start with "_"?

Tags: c, objective-c, programming-languages, naming-conventions

Something I see ppl define the variable like this:

```
b2World *_world;
b2Body *_body;
CCSprite *_ball;
```

instead of

```
b2World *world;
b2Body *body;
CCSprite *ball;
```

I familiar with the second one, but not the first one. So, I checked the Wikipedia about naming convention:

> Names beginning with double underscore
>   or an underscore and a capital letter
>   are reserved for implementation
>   (compiler, standard library) and
>   should not be used (e.g. __reserved or
>   _Reserved).

So, is that any special meaning which is start with "_"?

The code I saw which using "_" to begin is here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls

[The wiki page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming))

Answer (score 13):

There's a long-standing convention among some Objective-C developers to prefix instance variables with an underscore. It can be helpful in several ways: one, it makes it easier to spot instance variables in a .m file; two, it relieves developers of having to come up with creative names for method parameters to avoid colliding with instance variable names; and three, as others have noted, it indicates that the instance variables are private, and therefore shouldn't be accessed willy nilly throughout the code.

In fact, I'd argue for avoiding accessing instance variables directly in methods other than accessors (getters and setters), `-dealloc`, and `-init...`. Not that you should never, ever use them anywhere else, but you should at least give it some thought before using an instance variable directly in other methods.

Answer (score 3):

It's really really helpful, but most people don't know why, and that's a shame.
Apple uses underscores to separate the way other objects access a particular object's variables, and the way a particular object access its own variables.
Now this may sound a little bit strange, but imagine the following: You probably all recognize the following compiler warning

```
.h
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) UITableView *tableView;

.m
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self loadSomethingElseForTableView:tableView];
}
```

This will result in a compiler warning, because it does not know wether you reference to the local variable "tableView", or the instance variable.
Therefore, Apple recommends you to add the following to the top of your @implementation.

```
@synthesize tableView = _tableView;
```

Now, when you reference to `_tableView`, the compiler knows that you mean the instance variable, and not the local one.

Also, this makes it a lot easier to understand the Garbage Collection in Obj-C, and to prevent making common mistakes.

For example, when doing the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSString *title;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.title = title; // Is not possible, since it's read only.
        title = title; // Is not possible, since it's the same (local) variable.
        // Changing the method to initWithTitle:(NSString *)aTitle;
        title = aTitle;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now, since you do not use the default setter (actually, you can't, because it's read-only) you **need** to retain the variable yourself.
This is a lot easier to remember when you give every instance variable a prefix (so you know you need to retain it yourself).

So, basically, it's important to understand the difference between `self.variable` and (`_`)`variable`. (that is: `self.variable` maps to `[self setVariable:...]` and `variable` maps directly to your pointer.

Furthermore, when you add it as a private variable, like this:

```
@interface TSSomeObject : NSObject {
@private
    NSString *_privateTitle;
}
@end
```

The underscore prefix isn't really necessary, unless you may encounter local variables that have the same name. Besides that, again, it's also an easy way to remind you that it's a local pointer and that you need to retain (and release) the variable when you assign it to your object.

What **is** wrong is to create a property with a underscore prefix, like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *_title;
```

That's really wrong, and I'm not even gonna explain why ;)

---

So yes! You should really use underscore prefixes, it makes your code a lot easier to read, and to interpret by the compiler! In Xcode 4, Apple even added these `@synthesize`s to the default templates.

Answer (score 0):

Usually they're used for variables that shouldn't be accessed outside the current file/module/namespace/whatever, in languages that don't support restricting access with something like a `private` keyword

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-1001757

Both by convention and recommendation in the above document, you should prefix ivars with an underscore.

Admittedly, it is in reference to explicitly set ivars for properties.

But the usage is the same, to indicate the usage of an ivar wherever it is seen.

I am however open to the possibility, that in that context, the use of an underscore prefixed ivar could signal to the user that they are doing something wrong. Meanwhile a postfixed underscore could be used for pure ivars that are meant to be accessed directly.

This blog has some good thoughts from an experienced practitioner and it recommends using prefixed underscores.

http://blog.bignerdranch.com/463-a-motivation-for-ivar-decorations/

Wether you choose to use prefixed underscores to decorate your own ivars, there is at least some evidence that some kind of decoration will help you avoid bugs. And prefix'd underscores are the most common decoration.

Answer (score -1):

Apple reserves names beginning with underscore for its own private ivars and methods.  In Objective-C on any Apple platform, it is recommended that you do not prefix your identifiers with an underscore.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html

Comment: -1 Apple *does not* reserve instance variables prefixed with underscores. Quite the reverse, they encourage all developers to use underscore prefixes for ivars; in fact, the autosynthesis mechanism introduced in Xcode 4.5 synthesizes prefixed ivars by default.

Comment: @jlehr: Your latter point isn't true.  Autosynthesized ivars have the exact same name as the property by default.

Comment: @JeremyP: jlehr is correct about his former point.  Your link points to an article about naming methods, not ivars.  The ivar-pertaining companion can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-1001757

Comment: Correction of my earlier statement: ivars sythesized by the default `@synthesize` directive have the exact same name.  ivars autosynthesized with newer versions of clang are underscore-prefixed (as @jlehr said), and explicit `@synthesize property_name=ivar_name` declarations do what they're told, of course.

Comment: As Slipp points out, this answer is incorrect, Apple does explicitly recommend the usage of a prefixed underscore for ivars. Although I'll admit, this is in the context of synthesizing a property. Wether they recommend it more generally, don't know...